# Getting groups, root user belongs to

Tags: c++, linux

When I'm trying go get `groups` for root user in bash, I receive `root` as output (which is expected and obvious). But, then I'm looking in `/etc/group`, I can see that no users at all are mentioned in root group. And when I'm trying to get group info for `root` group from code like this:

```
group* groupInfo = getgrgid(0);
```

group member list `groupInfo->gr_mem` is empty.

How do I get real group member list and why root user isn't mentioned neither in /etc/group nor in `gm_mem` member of `group`?

For mbratch's comment:
I faced this issue on Open Suse and Ubuntu. Still, even if user does belongs to group with appropriate name, I don't see the way to determine this fact so far.

Comment: In some Linux distros, by default, a user is a member of a group by their own name, even though it's not explicit in `/usr/group`. `getgrgid` follows `/etc/group`. Which are you using? Ubuntu? Fedora?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/group` file is used to set only *secondary* groups of users. The *primary* group is saved in `/etc/passwd`. This is the reason why `root` user is not in `root` group in `/etc/group`: `root` is the *primary* group of `root` user.

To get this information you should use `getpwuid`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, if I want to check if user belongs to any group, I need to refer both to `getgrgid` for all secondary group entries and to `getpwuid` for primary one, right?

Comment: Exactly. `getpwuid` will return to you a structure containing all fields of `/etc/passwd` for the given UID, one of those is the GUID of the primary group.